# remove() in jquery is not working

Tags: jquery

Hi can anyone tell me why `remove()` is not working in the following code

```
  $("#mydropdown_for_month").change(function(){
  $("#mydropdown_for_day").empty();
   for (var i=1; i<=31; i++)
   {options += '<option>' + i+'</option>';}
   $('#mydropdown_for_day').after().html(options);
```

I have two select boxes with ids `mydropdown_for_month` and `mydropdown_for_day`. The problem is that when I click any month in the first dropdown , second dropdown normally shows all the dates from for loop as i have mentioned but when i again change the month say from feb to april the second dropdown show dates from 1 to 31 twice (may be 1 to 31 for first i select month and 1 to 31 again for the second time when i select april). so to solve this i put the following statement `$("#mydropdown_for_day").empty();` so that on every selection from the first dropdown , second dropdown's all previous options get removed but no use.

Please help me where am i making mistake?

Comment: Because there's no remove() call? :)

Comment: There is no call to `remove()` in your code. The `options` variable is never declared. `after()` cannot be called without arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove all options you could use:

```
 $("#mydropdown_for_day option").remove()
```

Comment: I have tried the same statement but it it again showing twice on twice selection

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to replace the options currently in the select box with new options, I'd do it like this:

```
$("#mydropdown_for_month").change(function(){
    var options, i;

    options = $("#mydropdown_for_day")[0].options;
    options.length = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 31; i++) { // I'm guessing you'd want to use a different upper limit here for different months
        options[options.length] = new Option(i, i);
    }
});
```

It's rather more direct than building up an HTML string. The `Option` constructor accepts up to four arguments: The text to display, the value, whether the option is the default, and whether it's selected. The `options` pseudo-array (it's not really an array) on the raw `select` element contains the options. You can add to it by assigning to an index above the last-used index (as above), or by calling its `add` method (not `push` as it would be with an array).

---

**Update**: Below you've asked

> but what is wrong with my code ... where is the mistake?

Fundamentally, the mistake is that that's not how you add/remove options; hence the above. It seems like it should work (after all, that's how you specify them in HTML), but in my experience it doesn't work well-cross browser. The above works in every browser I've ever seen.

Other specifics:

- You've called [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) with no arguments, which doesn't make any sense; `after` is for inserting content *after* things, so you have to say what the content is. I wouldn't be surprised if there were an error because of that.
- You've never declared or initialized your `options` variable.

Comment: @mehwish: Fundamentally, what's wrong with your code is that that's now how you add/remove options to/from select boxes. See also the other notes in the updated answer.